# Spark Structured Streaming performance for Scala vs Python

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Hi~ I'm going to develop a mini-batched program with *Kafka + Spark Structured Streaming*. But I am very confused, whether to use python or scala, which is faster. It would be better if there is any benchmark performance result about Spark Structured Streaming between Scala and Python.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an issue.

Only thing are that 1) Scala is faster but the scale of data per microbatch may mean less of an impact and 2) Scala has dataset support for types, pyspark does not.

Most use Scala, pyspark more for data science.

That said real-time machine learning may well be better with pyspark. See for example: https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-real-time-prediction-pipeline-using-spark-structured-streaming-and-microservices-626dc20899eb

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, it's fine for me that pyspark does not have dataset support for types. I'v did a test in my machine. Test for 10 million message from kafka, and the result is: Python costs 16.66 seconds, while Scala costs 16.98 seconds. It seems that Python is faster than Scala.

Comment: dataset support is still wip, so I agree

Comment: not conclusive enuff. for engineering i would stick with scala. but my preference.